# Update model from database - refresh one table

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to refresh only one entity in entity framework designer? Every time I refresh model from database, it refreshes all entities. The problem is that this mechanism doesn't recognize properly primary keys in views, so I have to correct it manually. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything. When you update model using the GUI designer, the entire storage schema is regenerated. At least, that's how it works in Entity Framework 1.

Comment: CTP versions seemed to have this functionality (http://tinyurl.com/yfxuczo). This is huge flaw, specially in bigger models. I hope they will implement it in EF4 designer.

Comment: You should consider filing a connect report, then. That said, EF 4 does have other ways of customizing your model. You might consider code-only, given what you're doing.

Comment: I like GUI designer. It does its job well, but has some flaws. When corrected, I'll need nothing more.

Comment: In EF 4 you could consider model-first, then.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you if you can or can't do it, but I have one clue how to figure it out.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2

EdmGen2 contains source code and dll probably with functionalities from usual EdmGen.
Unfortunately I didn't have time to investigate this further. Hope this helps.